# No surround sound in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, hdmi, music, speakers

I have been looking everywhere for a while now, trying to set up my laptop to transmit complete surround sound. However, it never works. Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to play music from my laptop over HDMI to a 7.2 HT System. But, when I connect it over HDMI, only the front 2 speakers work. That doesn't make sense, because I have already set up my speakers configured for 7.1, http://puu.sh/3GgsR.png

When I press `Test`, all the individual speakers play the test tone. But, when I play a song using Windows Media Player, or Winamp, or VLC, only the first 2 work. I have tried several different kinds of music, even FLAC, but they all do the same.

Another strange phenomenon, music played through Internet Explorer plays on all speakers. That is the only app surround works fine on.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at any advanced setting in the players to ensure that they are pointed to your desired device instead of default audio device? I would look there fist, especially since test and IE work over all speakers.

Comment: It happens because MP3 is a stereo format, which can only be played on 2 speakers. I am just transmitting an mp3/stereo stream from my laptop, so that the receiver can fill up the rest of the speakers with a Dolby PL II system. I figured it out after looking stuff up more.damn windows..Linux never caused me this problem..